# Installing from packages in /usr/bin

Tags: installation, netbeans

I'm a total ubuntu newbie and I have a doubt regarding installation from downloaded packages (from websites).

I have been trying to install Netbeans 7 in ubuntu 11.10. I have downloaded the .sh package from the Netbeans website and I can install it but only in a folder inside my user folder.

I have read somewhere that programs are installed in /usr/bin, and for example I have installed the Java SDK in that location. But i can't install Netbeans there. If I try to put it in the /usr/bin I get the message that is a read-only folder and I can't hit Next...

And I wonder if there's a way to install it in that location because I wouldn't like to have it installed within my documents.

I haven't found any info related to this searching in google, so really thankful if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome. Usually in Ubuntu you don't directly deal with `/usr/bin` directory when installing a new program. If you come from the Windows world then usually you don't extract program to Program Files and start using it. You execute the installation wizard to do the installation for you.

Same here. You can install a program by searching it in the *Software Center* and clicking the install button.

In cases, like yours, where the software was downloaded from a website you usually download a *.deb* file that you can install by opening a terminal and executing `sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb`.

Make sure you've downloaded the Ubuntu package and for the right architecture (32-bit / 64-bit).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your answer!!
I have downloaded the right file, but for linux is .sh extension. When I execute the installation wizard I have to choose the installation path and I only can install in my home folder. I would believe that it's not good practice to have programs installed in the home folder, right?

Comment: @user50122 You can specify /opt as the installation directory when the installer prompts for it

Comment: /opt is on my home folder as well? 
My real question would be, when you install a program using the repositories it is installed somewhere in the root directory for programs, right?
So when I have to use an installation method in which I have to specify the directory, which one should I use?
Is it this one that you mention, /opt?
Many thanks for your collaboration, and sorry if I don't understand at first try :)

Comment: /opt is not on your home directory, that would be /home/your_user/opt , yes, you can use /opt for other software. You will need to run the installer with root.